# Problem in Creating an angular project with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm trying to create a project after installing angular-cli in my system. When I give `ng new project-name` command I'm getting an error as follows.

ERROR:

> ```
> 21328 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Windows\System32\sampleproject\node_modules\.staging\typescript-d81c34c0\lib\typescript.js'
> 21329 verbose cwd C:\Windows\System32\sampleproject
> 21330 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
> 21331 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--quiet"
> 21332 verbose node v12.6.0
> 21333 verbose npm  v6.9.0
> 21334 error path C:\Windows\System32\sampleproject\node_modules\.staging\typescript-d81c34c0\lib\typescript.js
> 21335 error code EPERM
> 21336 error errno -4048
> 21337 error syscall unlink
> 21338 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Windows\System32\sampleproject\node_modules\.staging\typescript-d81c34c0\lib\typescript.js'
> 21338 error  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Windows\System32\sampleproject\node_modules\.staging\typescript-d81c34c0\lib\typescript.js'] {
> 21338 error   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Windows\System32\sampleproject\node_modules\.staging\typescript-d81c34c0\lib\typescript.js'] {
> 21338 error     errno: -4048,
> 21338 error     code: 'EPERM',
> 21338 error     syscall: 'unlink',
> 21338 error     path: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\sampleproject\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-d81c34c0\\lib\\typescript.js'
> 21338 error   },
> 21338 error   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\sampleproject\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-d81c34c0\\lib\\typescript.js'",
> 21338 error   errno: -4048,
> 21338 error   code: 'EPERM',
> 21338 error   syscall: 'unlink',
> 21338 error   path: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\sampleproject\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-d81c34c0\\lib\\typescript.js',
> 21338 error   parent: 'sampleproject'
> 21338 error }
> 21339 error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
> 21339 error It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
> 21339 error or that you lack permissions to access it.
> 21339 error
> 21339 error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
> 21339 error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
> 21339 error the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
> 21340 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
> ```

What is the problem with this and how to resolve this?

Can some one help me out with this?

Comment: 1. npm version? 
2. are you running any other `ng serve` in another commandline?

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems is a Windows permissions problem, firstly try to do the following:

`npm cache clean`

If that doesn’t fix the problem, look at `%APPDATA%\npm-cache` to clean this directory, or in PowerShell you can run, `$env:APPDATA\npm-cache`.

After cleaning the cache, you may still be left with remnants.  Manually remove everything in that directory, and try again.